# Why doesn't TeamCity recognize docker server properties with the jetbrains/agent image?

Tags: docker, teamcity, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have an ECS Fargate service running the jetbrains/teamcity-agent image. This is connected to my TeamCity Host which is running on an EC2 instance(windows).

When I check whether the agent is capable of running docker commands, it shows the following errors:

Unmet requirements: 
docker.server.osType contains linux
docker.server.version exists

Under Agent Parameters -> Configuration Parameters, I can see the docker version and the dockerCompose.version properly. Is there a setting that I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access a docker socket in fargate, **Fargate does not support running docker commands**, there is a [proposed ticket](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/95) for this feature.

> the issue with "docker.server.osType" not showing up usually means
> that the docker command run from the agent cannot connect with the
> docker daemon running. This is usually due to a lack of permissions,
> as docker by default only allows connections from root and users of
> the group docker

[Teamcity-Unmet-requirements-docker-server-osType-contains-linux](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003648440-https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003648440-Unmet-requirements-docker-server-osType-contains-linux)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issues got them fixed by adding "build agent" user in "docker" group and restarted/rebooted the server.

Where `build agent user` ==> Means the user with which your TeamCity services are running.

Command to add a user to group

```
#chmod -a -G docker <userasperyourrequirement>
```

Command to reboot the server:

```
 #init 6
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, I just had to swap out `chmod` for `usermod` to add my user to the `docker` group:
`sudo usermod -a -G docker <BUILD_AGENT_USER_NAME>`
`sudo reboot now`